# Transpose of a 3d list

Tags: python, list, 3d

I have tried this the below mentioned code:

```
counts=[[[(col.count(i)) for i in range(1,n)] for col in matrix] for matrix in lists] 
print(counts)
```

and the code gives me

```
[[[1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]], [[4, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 3, 0]]]
```

this output

here 3, 5 element list created. I want 5, 3 element list. The output should look like:

```
 [[[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]], [[4, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 3, 0]]]
```

what kind of work should be performed on 'counts' list so that I get this desired output.

Comment: It would be helpful if you also shared the definition of `lists` in your code, so people have a minimal, complete and verifiable example to work with https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is the input list you want to transpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't really transpose anything as far as i can tell; this is just a reshaping. `numpy` lets you do that this way:

```
import numpy as np

lst = [[[1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]], 
       [[4, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 3, 0]]]
arr = np.array(lst)
res = arr.reshape((2, 5, 3))
```

which gives:

```
[[[1 1 1]
  [1 0 1]
  [1 1 0]
  [1 1 1]
  [0 1 1]]

 [[4 0 0]
  [0 0 1]
  [2 1 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [1 3 0]]]
```